# Trouble writing from a MIPS program to a .txt file

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I am simply trying to write the string "It Works!" into the file "myFile.txt". Both file_work.s and myFile.txt are in the same directory.

I am using SPIM.

I have tried saving the file name in .data as an absolute path with no success.

```
# file name: file_work.s
# 

.data
fout:   .asciiz "myFile.txt"      # filename for output
buffer: .asciiz "It Works!"

.text
main:
  # Open (for reading) a file
  li $v0, 13       # system call for open file
  la $a0, fout     # output file name
  li $a1, 0        # flags
  syscall          # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)

  move $t0, $v0    # save file descriptor in $t0

  # Write to file just opened
  li $v0, 15       # system call for read to file
  la $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to write
  li $a2, 32       # hardcoded buffer length
  move $a0, $t0    # put the file descriptor in $a0
  syscall          # write to file

  la $a0, buffer #load the address into $a0
  li $v0, 4     # print the string out
  syscall

  # Close the file
  li $v0, 16       # system call for close file
  move $a0, $t0    # Restore fd
  syscall          # close file

  li $v0, 10        # end the file
  syscall
```

Comment: You're opening the file for read only, then writing to it.  You might also inspect the return values from the various syscalls to see if they are reporting error or success.

Comment: @ErikEidt what data type is the file descriptor? Also if the bytes written is -1 why would the write be failing?

Comment: Please re-read my last, above.  The data type for file descriptor is small integer for success and negative for failure.

Comment: Thanks for answering the one about fd data type. I should clarify that I know a negative number of bytes written means failure. I was wondering if you had insights into why the write was failing by looking at my code. Your last doesn't answer that.

Comment: Yes, but my first does.  Re-read the first sentence I said.

Comment: Oh my mistake I forgot to mention in my first response that I changed the flag to 9 and then still got -1 for bytes transferred

Comment: Hmm... I tried it that way and it successfully writes to the file: I got 32 in `$v0`.  Tried it with the file non-existent (it gets created) and with it already existing (the 32  bytes are appended).  (You're sure the open worked, right?)

Comment: Ok, I was using MARS, but tried it with QtSPIM, and the open failed first time.  I then used a command line (cmd) on windows, first changed the current directory (cd) to one that is writeable, then ran QtSPIM, and it did successfully add 32 bytes to the file.

Comment: With QtSPIM, tried it with the file non-existent (it gets an error on open) and with it already existing (the 32 bytes are appended).  So, there is a difference in flag 9 between QtSPIM (it won't create the file if it doesn't already exist) and MARS (it will create the file if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: Ok, the flag to create file if needed is 0x100 for QtSPIM, so if you use 0x109, you'll create a writeable file if it doesn't already exist and append if it does already exist -- equivalent to MARS flag 9.

Comment: When you say you changed the current directory to one that is writable do ou mean the directory with the .s file in it? And then you ran the .s file from the command line?

Comment: I run cmd, use the cd command to change to a user writable directory/folder, then run qtspim from the cmd, e.g. using "C:\Program Files (x86)\qtspim\qtspim.exe".

Comment: I am using a mac so I don't know how well your advice translates. I don't know how to run QtSpim from the command line, I don't have a Program Files directory like yours. Also why does running from the command line differ from running the file in the QtSpim simulator? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Got it to work.